# Extract data from a specific cell in a large number of worksheets

Tags: excel-formula

I have a large number of worksheets (named 1,2...100). Trying to figure out a way to extract the data from A1 in every sheet, without having to type 100 cells manually.

Would like a summary sheet like this:

A1: ='1'!A1

A2: ='2'!A1

...

A3: ='100'!A1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,1,1,1,ROW()))`

Enter in *Cell A1* then copy or autofill to remaining cells.